# HTACCESS redirect .com.au to only .com

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Below is my HTACCESS in which I am redirecting my website with below rules.

https://rosterelf.com will be redirected to https://www.rosterelf.com/

http://www.rosterelf.com will be redirected to https://www.rosterelf.com

rosterelf.com will be redirected to https://www.rosterelf.com/

So basically it will check if url does not have **www** or **https** then it will simply direct with it. This is working fine for me.

However, now I want to redirect all my urls with **.com.au** as well ..

I should be able to redirect https://www.rosterelf.com.au/ to https://www.rosterelf.com/ with same above conditions. By checking **https** or **non www to www**.

I have tried various codes like

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =m.somesite.com.au
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.somesite.com.au/$1 [R,L]
```

and others by adding in my existing htaccess file but it doesnt work in few cases like in my inner pages .. or without https. Here is my current htaccess file looks like.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    

    RewriteEngine On

    ##
    ## You may need to uncomment the following line for some hosting environments,
    ## if you have installed to a subdirectory, enter the name here also.
    ##
    # RewriteBase /

    ##
    ## Uncomment following lines to force HTTPS.
    ##
    # RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    # RewriteRule (.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [L,R=301]
    
    # CONDITIONS FOR ONLY LIVE SITE STARTS 
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
    # CONDITIONS FOR ONLY LIVE SITE ENDS  
    
    


    ##
    ## Black listed folders
    ##
    RewriteRule ^bootstrap/.* index.php [L,NC]
    RewriteRule ^config/.* index.php [L,NC]
    RewriteRule ^vendor/.* index.php [L,NC]
    RewriteRule ^storage/cms/.* index.php [L,NC]
    RewriteRule ^storage/logs/.* index.php [L,NC]
    RewriteRule ^storage/framework/.* index.php [L,NC]
    RewriteRule ^storage/temp/protected/.* index.php [L,NC]
    RewriteRule ^storage/app/uploads/protected/.* index.php [L,NC]

    ##
    ## White listed folders
    ##
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/.well-known/*
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/storage/app/uploads/public/.*
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/storage/app/media/.*
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/storage/app/resized/.*
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/storage/temp/public/.*
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/themes/.*/(assets|resources)/.*
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/plugins/.*/(assets|resources)/.*
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/modules/.*/(assets|resources)/.*
    RewriteRule !^index.php index.php [L,NC]

    ##
    ## Block all PHP files, except index
    ##
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.php$
    RewriteRule !^index.php index.php [L,NC]

    ##
    ## Standard routes
    ##
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

As you can see above htaccess I have used below 3 lines of code to redirect non www to www and http to https ..

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Now my question is, how can I make all the existing condition work with able to redirect .com.au to .com ?

Can someone guide me please ..

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your shown samples, please have your htaccess with following Rules.
Please make sure you clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
  Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine ON
RewriteBase /

##NO https, no www rules
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^rosterelf\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]

##NO https with www rules
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.rosterelf\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]


##NO https, no www rules
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(rosterelf\.com)\.au$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]

##NO https with www rules
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(rosterelf\.com)\.au$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]

## Black listed folders
##
RewriteRule ^(bootstrap|config|vendor)/.* index.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^storage/(cms|logs|framework)/.* index.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^storage/temp/protected/.* index.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^storage/app/uploads/protected/.* index.php [L,NC]

##
## White listed folders
##
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/.well-known/*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/storage/app/uploads/public/.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/storage/app/media/.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/storage/app/resized/.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/storage/temp/public/.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/themes/.*/(assets|resources)/.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/plugins/.*/(assets|resources)/.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/modules/.*/(assets|resources)/.*
RewriteRule !^index.php index.php [L,NC]

##
## Block all PHP files, except index
##
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^index\.php index.php [L,NC]

##
## Standard routes
##
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thank you so much @RavinderSingh13 .. I will check and get back to you with my updates. Thanks.

Comment: @MittulAtTechnoBrave, Hey Mittul, Greetings!! could you please do let me know if my code has worked for you, very excited to know if this has helped you or not :) cheers

Comment: Sorry for late reply .. I was not logged in .. Yea your answer helped me and I resolved using your code .. Thank you so much

Comment: @MittulAtTechnoBrave, your welcome, very happy to help here :) keep posting, keep sharing on this great site cheers :)

Answer (score 2):

You can redirect both domains to `https` and add `www.` in single redirect rule. Make sure to keep this new redirect rule **before other rules:**

```
RewriteEngine On

## add www and turn on https in same rule
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

# other rules come below this line

##
## Black listed folders
##
RewriteRule ^bootstrap/.* index.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^config/.* index.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^vendor/.* index.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^storage/cms/.* index.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^storage/logs/.* index.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^storage/framework/.* index.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^storage/temp/protected/.* index.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^storage/app/uploads/protected/.* index.php [L,NC]

##
## White listed folders
##
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/.well-known/*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/storage/app/uploads/public/.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/storage/app/media/.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/storage/app/resized/.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/storage/temp/public/.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/themes/.*/(assets|resources)/.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/plugins/.*/(assets|resources)/.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/modules/.*/(assets|resources)/.*
RewriteRule !^index.php index.php [L,NC]

##
## Block all PHP files, except index
##
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.php$
RewriteRule !^index.php index.php [L,NC]

##
## Standard routes
##
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: Thank you so much @anubhava .. I will check and get back to you with my updates. Thanks.